# How to check spatial autocorrelation correctly in a glm

Tags: r, regression, autocorrelation

I ran a binomial glm as below and from plotting observations i know that there are many observations close to each other and i expect them to be highly correlated. For this matter after selecting the best model, I did the following to check for spatial autocorrelation (SAC) using Moran's I (not sure if u did this correctly too). But after much reading I found you can't use Moran's I to test the SAC of a model with binomial response and should use join count.test.

```
#best model    
best_m <- glm(response ~ predictor 1 + predictor 2 +predictor1*predictor2, family=binomial("logit"), data= data1)

#check Spatial autocorrelation 
coords<-as.matrix(cbind(data1[,2],data1[,3])) #x and y geographic coordinates
nb <- knn2nb(knearneigh(coords, 1)) 
lstw <- nb2listw((knn2nb(knearneigh(coords, k=1))))

# Compute Moran's I using residuals of model and also raw data
moran.test(data1$response, nb2listw(nb, style = "B")) #check for raw data
moran.test(best_m$residuals, lstw) # there is SAC for model residuals
```

Comment: @reevesii thank you for editing my question in the required format

Comment: No problem. Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. Taking the tour, available [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), will provide insight on how to get more out of this site.

Comment: You may get a better response if you split this into two questions. One regarding the correct implementation of checking for SAC. Another to ask if you used the autocov_dist function correctly.